# Laravel Eloquent get multiple record with same foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys

I have 3 tables:

```
User
------------------
ID 
Name


Room
------------------
ID
Subject



Participate
-------------------
ID
room_id
user_id
```

and it's my sample data:

```
user                        room                    participate
-----------------           ----------------        ---------------------
ID     Name                 ID     subject          ID  room_id  user_id  
-----------------           ----------------        --------------------- 
1      john                 1      room1            1     1       1
2      sara                 2      room2            2     1       2
3      david                3      room3            3     3       3
                                                    4     3       2
                                                    5     3       1
                                                    6     2       1
```

Now I access to `user_id` but I want to find `room_id` that have shared with user_IDs in `participate` table. For example I have `user_id: 1` & `user_id: 2` and want to get shared room_id `1`. Already I filter participate model by `user_id` but I don't know to find room_id.

Thanks

Comment: show us what you have already tried.

Comment: Do you have eloquent models defined for your room and user tables?

Comment: @MubasharAbbas `$rooms = Participate::Where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)
                                ->orWhere('user_id', $request->to)
                                ->get();`

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo I added my code to commens.

Comment: I do not understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create such a query:

```
$usersIDs = [$userId, $secondUserId]; //here define user ids how many  you want

DB::table('room')->select('room.*')
    ->join('participate', 'participate.room_id', '=', 'room.id')
    ->join('user', 'user.id', '=', 'participate.user_id')
    ->whereIn('user.id', $usersIDs)
    ->havingRaw('count(user.id) = ?', [count($usersIDs)])
    ->groupBy('room.id')
    ->first();
```

Comment: Thanks but where is `$secondUserID`. you forget it. I want to get shared `room ID` `$firstUserId` and `$secondUserId`

Comment: How to accept filter when just retrieve 2 records, not more than 3. Means, if fetch 3 records and have 3 records, I don't want show room id. How to this? It's extra question

Comment: I've reedited again to show you haw to get the dynamic numbers of user's Ids.

Comment: No, I think you don't understand my means. For example I have `user_id` 12,13,14 that put in `room_id: 1` that in this way I don't want to show `room _id`. but if when I have `user_id` 18,19 that put in `room_id: 3` that's accept and show me.